# Unable to get property isFunction of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs, extjs4

I have a sencha architect project with ExtJS 4.2.2 and Architect 3.0.4.

On IE, I get some very mysterious, unexpected error when the proxy callback should be triggered.

```
Unable to get property isFunction of undefined or null reference
```

in line 472 of `Ext/src/data/Proxy.js`, which is

```
if (Ext.isFunction(batchOptions.callback)) {
```

Or, in other words, `Ext` is undefined!?

But I am well into the execution of the Ext application.
Dozens of calls to Ext.getCmp, Ext.getStore, Ext.create and Ext.define were already triggered successfully.

What exactly is `Ext`? Shouldn't this variable be global, so it is available anywhere anytime, whatever happens?

I would like to mention once again: this error only occurs in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have put the script tags for the Ext library before the script tags for your proxy.js?

As if default document mode is standards, not sure it might been the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I edited the question to be more specific: `Proxy.js` is `ext/src/data/Proxy.js`, so it *is* part of the Ext library.